# How to Tag a Docker Image in Azure DevOps?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops

I'm trying to dynamically tag my docker images that I'm building in Azure DevOps using `docker-compose`. I'm not sure how to set the tags?

Notice how I'm trying to set the Tag as a `variable` .. and then in the variable .. trying to join some constant string + build number...

-> `additionalImageTags: '${dockerCompose.imageTag}'`

```
resources:
- repo: self
queue:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604
steps:
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Build and Tag Images'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<snipped>'

    azureContainerRegistry: '<snipped>'

    dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml'

    additionalDockerComposeFiles: 'docker-compose.override.yml'

    qualifyImageNames: false

    action: 'Build services'

    additionalImageTags: '${dockerCompose.imageTag}'

    includeLatestTag: true
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be: `$(dockerCompose.imageTag)`, unless you have some other errors, which you dont share.